# The graphical elements of UIKit – what format are they?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uikit

For standard interface elements of the Apple's UIKit, how do apple store them? Are they stored as cocca touch code, pdf, images or other?

Thanks
Ross

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graphics are stored in crushed PNG format in an 'artwork' file in UIKit.

In a more general sense they are, of course, not just graphics - but can be likened to images painted in touch-receptive boxes.